# Pin identification for a salvaged LCD

Tags: arduino-nano, lcd

I salvaged an SPI interface LCD from an old CDMA telephone. It seems it uses SPI to display something on the screen. The pins marks are DATA, CS, SCLK, BL, VDD, GND, LED, A0, and RES. How do I wire it up to an Arduino?

Comment: i would try some of the LCD libraries, the ones people use for 5110 displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem pretty self-explanatory. Data, sclk and cs are normal SPI MOSI, CLK and CS. A0 is probably equivalent to C/D. RES is reset - tie high to run. Power and ground are obvious. The others look related to the back light.

However... How are you going to operate it? Do you know the SPI instructions to send? They will be specific to the display, so without a datasheet you're pretty much stuffed.

Comment: It's unlabeled, the silicon driver chip is on the glass covered by black silicone. I will try some LCD libraries. If there's a resolution mismatch, I will have to modify the library. A0 (and BL)is the only reason why I asked. Thank you